# How to insert a automatically generated Value "ID"

Tags: sql-server

I am working with an existing table using SQL. I have to insert the following data into this table. This is a homework Question! Below is the question and my code. I keep getting the following error.....Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ProductID', table 'jc0541535.dbo.Products'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. How do i get this ProductId to automatically generate?

> 1. ProductID: The next automatically generated ID
> 2. CategoryID: 4
> 3. ProductCode: dgx_640
> 4. ProductName: Yamaha DGX 640 88-Key Digital Piano
> 5. Description: Long description to come
> 6. ListPrice: 799.99
> 7. DiscountPercent: 0
> 8. DateAdded: Today's date/time
>
>    ### use column list for this statment

< This is the code that I used but it is not working properly. Can someone please point out why.

> INSERT INTO Products
>       (ProductID,CategoryID,ProductCode,ProductName,Description,ListPrice,DiscountPercent    ,DateAdded)
>       VALUES(DEFAULT,4,'dgx_640','Yamaha DGX 640 88-Key Digital Piano',
>       'Long description to come.',799.99,0,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

Comment: I just tried removing the Product column in the INSERT statement, and also the value that was in the VALUES statement....... now the Error is saying that the table Products is invalid? That is very strange and I don't understand

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `DEFAULT` -- just remove the column from the insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO Products (CategoryID,ProductCode,ProductName,Description,ListPrice,DiscountPercent ,DateAdded) 
VALUES(4,'dgx_640','Yamaha DGX 640 88-Key Digital Piano', 'Long description to come.',799.99,0,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f04d5/1)

Also, as others have said, make sure the column is an `IDENTITY`.

Comment: I just tried this bu now it is telling me that the error is:Invalid object name 'Products'........I do know that this is a valid table

Comment: "thanks" i believe that I will have to talk to the teacher about this one because we are unable to change the properties in our tables.

Answer (score 0):

Check the column properties in SQL Server Management Studio. Ensure that "Is Identity" is set to 'Yes' for ProductID and that "Identity Increment" is set to 1.

Comment: Thank you Ant P. You are correct, unfortunately I don't think that my teacher will allow me to alter the properties in the database. But yes you are correct!

Answer (score 0):

In design , click on the column product id -> column properties-> look for Identity Specification-> Identity Seed and increment by 1(or any desired value) and set (Is Identity)  to yes/true.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Unfortunately as students we are unable to change the properties in our databases, without making serious alterations that could ruin our remaining semester work. i will have to talk with her about the process she would like us to use in the morning. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @ProductID INTEGER

SELECT @ProductID = ISNULL(MAX(ProductID),1)
FROM Products

INSERT INTO products(ProductID, CategoryID, ...)
VALUES(@ProductID, 4, ...)
```

Will this be sufficient for your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

I had to take mine out and it looked like this: Try this

```sql
INSERT INTO Products
(CategoryID, ProductCode, ProductName, Description, ListPrice, DiscountPercent, DateAdded)
VALUES (4, 'dgx_640', 'Yamaha DGX 640 88-Key Digital Piano', 'Long description to come', 799.99, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```